# How to reduce the JS code in this example, while maintaining the same results

Tags: javascript

I have a page with hundreds of pre-written replies. Each with a Copy Button which will copy that paragraph. Currently, I have a function for each DIV ID, but I'm starting to think there is a better way. Perhaps having the JS know which of the buttons I clicked, and the corresponding DIV ID for that button.

Im new to Javascript, and learning bits by bits. Not sure what to search fo find my answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
function myFunction2() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput2");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
function myFunction3() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput3");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Something1" id="myInput1">
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something2" id="myInput2">
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something3" id="myInput3">
<button onclick="myFunction3()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Can you use `Jquery` for this?. It might easy and fast indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, the only thing that changes is the `id` of the element you target. So you can make a single function that accepts a parameter (*the `id` to use*) and use it by changing the parameter you pass to it.

```js
function myFunction(elementId) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(elementId);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Something1" id="myInput1">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput1')">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something2" id="myInput2">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput2')">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something3" id="myInput3">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput3')">Copy text</button>
```

---

As a next step (*a more opinionated approach*) i would add a custom data attribute on the buttons that tell it where to copy from, and also apply the handler in more modern ways.

```js
function myFunction(elementId) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(elementId);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}


document.querySelectorAll('[data-copy-from]').forEach(copyButton => {
  copyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const fromElement = copyButton.dataset.copyFrom;
    myFunction(fromElement);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Something1" id="myInput1">
<button data-copy-from="myInput1">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something2" id="myInput2">
<button data-copy-from="myInput2">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something3" id="myInput3">
<button data-copy-from="myInput3">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: You rock! That's the exact answer I was looking for :)

I honestly never knew you could put things into the () of a function. This changes so much! 

Thank you! :)

Comment: Any clue as to why I get this error?

Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function

https://jsfiddle.net/9yqnge2m/

Answer (score 1):

Give the buttons classes (or something else in common) instead, and then listen for a `click` on the document (or the container of the buttons) whose target is one of the buttons you care about. Then select the previous element to get to the `input`, and select and copy it:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.copy-btn')) {
    return;
  }
  const input = target.previousElementSibling;
  input.select();
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log("Copied the text: " + input.value);
});
```

```html
<input value="Something1">
<button class="copy-btn">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input value="Something2">
<button class="copy-btn">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input value="Something3">
<button class="copy-btn">Copy text</button>
```

Best to avoid inline handlers - they have numerous problems (scoping issues, escaping issues, required window pollution, conflating of content and presentation) and are generally considered to be pretty poor practice.

There's no need to give the inputs IDs either.

If all buttons in the container (or all buttons that come right after an input) are the ones you want the handler to run on, there's no need to give the buttons classes either - just check if the target matches `button` or `input + button`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use universal function, and pass the ID of every input:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Something1" id="myInput1">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput1')">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something2" id="myInput2">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput2')">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something3" id="myInput3">
<button onclick="myFunction('myInput3')">Copy text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Jquery` method, More compacted but buttons need unique ids as well.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var _id      = (this).id;
  var id       = _id.split("_").pop();
 
  alert("Copied The Text: "+ $("#myInput"+id).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Something1" id="myInput1">
<button id="button_1">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something2" id="myInput2">
<button id="button_2">Copy text</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="Something3" id="myInput3">
<button id="button_3">Copy text</button>
```